# How this StorageLevel work in CreateStream for Kafka and Mqtt

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using createStream for kafkaUtils like :

```
KafkaUtils.createStream[String, String, StringDecoder, PcapDecoder](
  ssc, 
  kafkaParams, 
  Map(topic -> 1), 
  StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK
).map(_._2)
```

and for MqttUtils like :

```
MQTTUtils.createStream(ssc, url, topic, StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER_2)
```

but it takes huge memory. How we can unpersist the stored data . or will it unpersist by default ?

Comment: Where do you see it persisting "huge memory"?

Comment: if I have 32 GB , it takes 10 GB or 20 GB for running this process using KafkaUtils .

Comment: Are you seeing out of memory exceptions? If not, let the GC do it's job. When needed, it will kick in for a cleanup.

Comment: Is there any problem with this Storage level ? how this storage Level work when a process is running .  Will it store the entire data of each window ?